# convert txt file to excel

Tags: excel, linux

i have so large file contain 20000 record like the 3 following record

```
-----
email: @hadara.ps'
inetnum:        37.8.0.0 - 37.8.63.255
netname:        HBSAGAZA
country:        PS
-----
email: @zaytona.ps'
inetnum:        46.60.36.0 - 46.60.36.255
netname:        ZAYTONA-NETWORK
country:        PS
-----
NetRange:       173.245.48.0 - 173.245.63.255
NetName:        CLOUDFLARENET
Country:        US
email: @cloudflare.com
-----
```

as you see each record separated with 5 ----- 
and contain 4 things in it

-they are not same letter case ( ex. some NetName / netname )
-( NetRange = inetnum ) 
-they not in the same order

i guess it easy to solve names difrance by replace

but how do i transform this file into excel file and not effected by there order

the expected output like this excel with 4 column

```
country  email   netname    inetnum
   xx      xx      xxx        xxx
   xx      xx      xxx        xxx
```

Comment: Fairly straightforward to use Power Query. Suggest you try something and show us your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a shell script, you can transform this into a csv file, which you can open with excel and convert to other compatible files.

try the below perl script, I only showed examples of two fields, but you can easy extend it for the remaining

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
%row=("email"=>"email","netname"=>"netname");

while(<>){
    if(/^netname:\s*(.*)/i){
        $row{"netname"}=$1;
    }elsif(/^email:\s*(.*)/i){
        $row{"email"}=$1;
    }elsif(/^---/ && length(keys(%row))){
        print '"'.$row{"email"}.'","'.$row{"netname"}.'"'."\n";
        %row=();
    }
}
```

sample output

```
>cat test.txt | perl test.pl 

"email","netname"
"@hadara.ps'","HBSAGAZA"
"@zaytona.ps'","ZAYTONA-NETWORK"
"@cloudflare.com","CLOUDFLARENET"
```

Comment: worked perfectly <3

Answer (score 0):

There's probably thousands of other methods, but here's mine with 3 column helpers.
One to fix the name of the variables (MID, LOWERCASE). One to get the indexes of each record(COUNTIF). And one to extract the associated value (MID). The final table uses VLOOKUP and CONCAT.

Output :[image: Transform]

[Worksheet](https://covid19.framadrop.org/r/EuvWjWVoZw#yv5nm04vUcONHJTolKqZRz4uVCdtEjPoUG1rXiG6830=)